# Fire .click() event in controlgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

Trying to fire the .click() event for my controlgroup.

Coded HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
            <div id="gradegeoradio" data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend>
                    </legend>
                    <input id="grade" name="choose" value="Grade" type="radio"/>
                    <label for="grade">
                        Grade
                    </label>
                    <input id="geometry" name="choose" value="Geometry" type="radio"/>
                    <label for="geometry">
                        Geometry
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>...
```

HTML in DOM:

```
<div class="ui-content" role="main" data-role="content"> <div id="gradegeoradio" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br" data-role="fieldcontain"> <fieldset class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup"><div class="ui-controlgroup-label" role="heading"> </div> <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls"> <div class="ui-radio"> </div> <div class="ui-radio"><input id="geometry" type="radio" value="Geometry" name="choose"> </input><label class="ui-btn ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last ui-radio-on ui-btn-active ui-btn-up-c" for="geometry" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c"> <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-right ui-controlgroup-last"> <span class="ui-btn-text">

                        Geometry

</span></span></label></div></div></fieldset></div>
```

JQuery trying to fire event:

```
$("#geometry").click();
```

Event listener:

```
$("#geometry, #grade").click(function(){do stuff after click}
```

I'm kind of new to all this, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry the HTML in the DOM is all clustered, I copy and pasted it and I couldn't figure out how to format it.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: No error, it just wont fire.

Comment: I hope you're executing the second snippet first?

Comment: I am trying to get the `$("#geometry, #grade").click(function(){...` to fire programatically, without physically clicking on it.

Comment: It should work. http://jsfiddle.net/X2ExM/1/ Maybe the event handler itself is broken?

Comment: Actually @bvukelic is correct. I noticed in your code that you had the event listener first, then called the event.  I had mine like this: `$(document).ready(function() {try{$("#geometry").click();}catch{}` ...then later I had `$("#geometry, #grade").click(function(){do stuff after click}` when I moved the `$("#geometry").click();` to under `$("#geometry, #grade").click(function(){do stuff after click}`, it worked

Comment: Added this to answers for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to summarize the answer given in comments.

You need to have the binding first, and then triggering. So:

```
$("#geometry, #grade").click(function(){do stuff after click}
```

must come before

```
$('#geometry').click();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/X2ExM/1/

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to bind an event to your geometry radio button which I think is what your trying to do you could use something like this

```
$('#geometry, #grade').bind('click', function() {
    //do some thing
});
$('#geometry, #grade').trigger('click');
```

Comment: This is wrong. The bind will correctly bind the handler to both `#geometry`, and `#grade`, but OP only wants to 'click' on `#geometry`, not both.

Comment: Simply remove #grade from the trigger if OP only wants geometry to be bound.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   bind and trigger...
```

use this , this is working

```
     $('#gradegeoradio').bind('click', function() {
      alert("hello to all");
     });

     $('#gradegeoradio').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Unless OP has order of binding and triggering mixed up, this is exactly what s/he is doing.